# Running a process in the background using &

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos

I have created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    echo "1" >> test.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

If I run the command using **./exm.sh &** it runs on the background as expected and it appends 1 to the file test.tx

After a few minutes I type **logout**, as far as I know the expected behaviour is to close all the children processes of the session, but if I login again and run p**s auwx | grep exm**, the process is still there and it is writing to the file.
Is this the expected behaviour?
I have the same results with fresh installation of CentOS 7 and Ubuntu latest.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/115999/if-i-launch-a-background-process-and-then-log-out-will-it-continue-to-run

Comment: @nkn Possible but I try to give `shopt -s  huponexit` and run the script. It remains  alive. Interesting, as always, to read Gilles on [Unix SE page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/process-descendants) about how to kill process group...

Comment: Gotcha: `trap  "pkill -P $$"  EXIT ` and after execute the script and whatever... when you exit it will kill all the children of the terminal. But the reason why `shopt -s huponexit` doesn't work remain.

Answer (score 0):

It is not what is commonly configured on different OS. 
If you want to change the behavior  of your logout, you can edit 
file 
1. ~/.bash_logout
    -if you are using bash
2. ~/.logout 
    -if you are using csh

Please see reference for more info.
[Unix Logout Command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-run-commands-when-you-log-out/)